# how to send info to the root view controller after changing uitabbar programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitabbar

I am currently switching uitabbar selection programmatically using

```
[myTabBarController setSelectedIndex:index]
```

but at the same time I want to send some info to the root controller of the newly selected uitabbar item. How can I do that?

To be specific I have a search box in home page and when user types in search string and clicks search I want the search results to appear under another uitabbar item ie search. How can I send the search string to the new root view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UINavigationController *newlySelectedRootController = [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index];
```

from here on you can do whatever you want to `newlySelectedViewController`.

Comment: though your comment helped me, it should actually be                    UINavigationController *newlySelectedRootController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];

Comment: @user1475962 you posted no useful code - how am I supposed to exactly know what actual classes and indices you use? And the accept function is exactly for "answers that heped".

Comment: done but can you edit your answer and change the type of returning object to UINavigationController ?